# Select multiple tables with WHERE

Tags: php, sql

Can somebody tell me how to select multiple tables with WHERE in the query?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM leerlingen, leraren WHERE voornaam= '$username' AND password= '$password'";
```

Because this query gives an error

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Any errors?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.*, 
       table2.* 
FROM table1 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
WHERE table1.field LIKE "Hello" 
  AND table2.field LIKE "World;
```

This query should do what you are asking: Selecting everything from two different tables having different conditions in the WHERE part.
As someone else said, try to always use explicit JOIN syntax as is more readable and self-explanatory.

Since the code you wrote does not make it clear if you did, I will strongly suggest you use some sort of input validation and escaping to prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple tables in where clause you have to use join between those tables

```
   select le.*,l.* from leerlingen le join  leraren l on le.col=l.col
    where l.col1=value --table leraren in where
       and le.col1=value --table leerlingen in where
```

And then you can apply `where`  filter on them

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.column_names, 
       t2.column_names 
FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id 
WHERE t1.voornam = $username AND t1.password = $password t2.field ='some value';